# Zks Servlet.service() NPE when using a jpa repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, zk

I'm currently having a confusingly frustrating issue.

I'm starting a Spring Boot + ZK webapp. So far, I did a secured login that redirects to a different page according to the role of the user loging in. This data is stored in my MySQL database, which I access with JPA. Because of this and some earlier testing, I know my configuration is working as expected between ZK, Spring and JPA.

Now I'm trying to show a list of users for a SuperUser role. For this, I use the default named query findAll(), but that's exacly where I'm having the problems. If I try to use my repo in my ViewModel class, I got a NullPointerException exactly at the line where I'm using said repo. The query itself is not being called, it brakes when it founds the repo.

Reading through a lot of other cases, I concluded that my config is ok (plus the fact that I already have my repo working for the login), so there has to be another issue, which pointed me to the DHtmlLayoutServlet. STS throws 2 error stacks:

Stack 1:

```
ERROR org.zkoss.bind.impl.ParamCall - 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.project.controllers.su.SuperUserPanelVM.init(SuperUserPanelVM.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.ParamCall.call(ParamCall.java:172)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.AbstractAnnotatedMethodInvoker.invokeMethod(AbstractAnnotatedMethodInvoker.java:112)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.AbstractAnnotatedMethodInvoker.invokeMethod(AbstractAnnotatedMethodInvoker.java:78)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.init(BinderImpl.java:333)
    at org.zkoss.bind.AnnotateBinder.init(AnnotateBinder.java:58)
    at org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer.doBeforeComposeChildren(BindComposer.java:205)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.doBeforeComposeChildren(UiEngineImpl.java:999)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:939)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:897)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:784)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:844)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:802)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:748)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:469)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:377)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:220)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:147)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1626)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Stack 2

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() para servlet [DHtmlLayoutServlet] lanzó excepción
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.project.controllers.su.SuperUserPanelVM.init(SuperUserPanelVM.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.ParamCall.call(ParamCall.java:172)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.AbstractAnnotatedMethodInvoker.invokeMethod(AbstractAnnotatedMethodInvoker.java:112)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.AbstractAnnotatedMethodInvoker.invokeMethod(AbstractAnnotatedMethodInvoker.java:78)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.init(BinderImpl.java:333)
    at org.zkoss.bind.AnnotateBinder.init(AnnotateBinder.java:58)
    at org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer.doBeforeComposeChildren(BindComposer.java:205)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.doBeforeComposeChildren(UiEngineImpl.java:999)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:939)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:897)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:784)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:844)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:802)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:748)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:469)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:377)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:220)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:147)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1626)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What I'm guessing out of this is that the problem is with ZKs Servlet... but why is it doing it while using an independent component? How could a JPA interface throw this exception **when I'm not using the data yet?** I'm very confused. So far I've tried different configurations that should do the same things, tried different anotations such as @WireVariable, @Resource and @Autowired in both, my custom LoginSuccessHandler and my SuperUserPanelVM (Resource and Autowired worked ok. WireVariable didn't, but I wasn't expecting it to work anyway) and checked for unmanaged dependencies.

There is data in the database. I'm querying for Users/Usuarios, which has 2 records. There are no nullable values in this table. Even if there were a null result set, since I'm not doing anything with it it shouldn't brake, so at least I know it doesn't like when I try to use the repo.

This is the (relevant part of) code I have:

SuperUserPanel.java

```java
public class SuperUserPanelVM {
    
    //(@WireVariable/@Resource/@Autowired) -> none worked, neither without annotations
    private UsuariosRepository usuariosRepository;
    
    @Init
    public void init() {
        usuariosRepository.findAll(); // -> It explodes here
    }
}
```

UsuariosRepository.java

```java
@Repository
public interface UsuariosRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuarios, Integer>{

    Usuarios findByCorreo(String correo); // This is used for the login
}
```

Usuarios.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="usuarios")
@NamedQuery(name="Usuarios.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM Usuarios u")
public class Usuarios {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_usuario")
    private int idUsuario;
    
    @Column(name="correo")
    private String correo;
    
    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(name="apellido_paterno")
    private String apellidoPaterno;
    
    @Column(name="apellido_materno")
    private String apellidoMaterno;
    
    @Column(name="telefono")
    private String telefono;
    
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password; //This is going to be further worked for stronger security, dw
    
    @Column(name="rol")
    private String rol;

    
    /* SETTES & GETTERS*/
}
```

DatabaseAuthProvider.java (Where the repo worked)

```java
@Component
public class DatabaseAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    
    @Resource
    private UsuariosRepository usuariosRepository;
    
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
        // check creds + redirect 
    }
}
```

The only place where I do reference to the DHtmlLayoutServlet is when registering said servlet:

ProjectWebConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
public class ProjectWebConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer{
    
    private static final Class<?>[] configurationClasses = new Class<?>[] {Config.class, Security.class};
    
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        registerListener(servletContext);   
        registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);
        registerSpringSecurityFilterChain(servletContext);
    }
    
    private void registerListener(ServletContext servletContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = createContext(configurationClasses);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());       
        servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionListener());
    }
        
    private void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(Config.class);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("zkLoader", new DHtmlLayoutServlet());

        dispatcher.setInitParameter("update-uri", "/zkau");
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.zul");
        
        dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("auEngine", new DHtmlUpdateServlet());
        dispatcher.addMapping("/zkau/*");
                
    }
    
    private void registerSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        //...
    }
    
    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext createContext(final Class<?>... annotatedClasses) {
       //...
    }
}
```

I think I'm overlooking something important, but I'm the kind of person that loses focus when frustrated. On other note, the Config.class in ProjectWebConfig.java has @ComponentScan, @EnableJpaRepositories and @EntityScan annotations with the correct URI.

I only need this to work. In other similar projects this very same config and architecture works just fine. I'm pretty much using a blueprint of other projects with the same tech, yet I just don't know what's going on with this error. I don't know if it's ZK's servlet doing, JPA's doing, a mix of both... Anyway, thank you for reading this far. I really hope someone can point me to the right direction. If more details are needed, Ill provide them as soon as I can. Have a nice day.

side note: I edited the class names. If you find something off about it, I will confirm if its wrong on my actual code of just in the snippets.

Comment: How do you expect Spring to inject something into a class that it doesn't manage? The `SuperUserPanelVM` isn't managed by spring and thus nothing will be injected.

Comment: I see your point, and I think I should've mentioned that I'm not using MVC architecture, but MVVM. The "blueprint" I'm following is actually three projects sharing overall the same configuration, and none of them inject/annotate their "controllers". They do inject Repositories, Services and such though. My `ComponentScan` also reaches the package where `SuperUserPanelVM` is. On that note, using `Component`, `Resource`, `Service` and `Controller` with it result in the same error (just checked). I hope that's what you meant?

Comment: No. Regardless if that class is annotated with one of those annotations the instance in question still isn't managed by Spring. You will actually have 2 instances, one from Spring and one from ZK which won't get anything injected. There is probably a way to inject dependencies from Spring into ZK components and that probably requires additional configuration. I'm not skilled in ZK so I cannot give a definitive answer on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't show the related zul code I'll assume you are applying the viewmodel by class name.

```
<window viewModel="@id('vm') @init('my.package.SuperUserPanelVM')" ...
```

This implies that the view model instance is created by ZK and not by Spring (which rules out the usage of spring's annotations `@Resource`/`@Autowired`, already mentioned in the first [comment by M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66570551/zks-servlet-service-npe-when-using-a-jpa-repository#comment117682008_66570551)).

So if ZK creates the view model then `@WireVariable` is the annotation to use (just trying to reduce the problem/solution space here).

```
@WireVariable
private UsuariosRepository usuariosRepository;
```

`@WireVariable` will 'search' for a bean with the variable name `usuariosRepository` (I assume that works, but ... it will not look inside the Spring Application context by default)

In order to do so you'll have to specify a `@VariableResolver` at your view model class to include spring beans into the variable resolution.
(**I guess that's what you forgot**).

```
import org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver

@VariableResolver(DelegatingVariableResolver.class)
public class SuperUserPanelVM {
  @WireVariable
  private UsuariosRepository usuariosRepository;
```

Now the @WireVariable should find the repository in the application context. In order to be sure just add a breakpoint inside `DelegatingVariableResolver` to verify this variable resolver is called and your spring application context actually contains a bean with the name 'usuariosRepository'.

To be extra sure you can give your repository an explicit name (just to be sure no one reconfigured the default bean naming convention):

```
@Repository("usuariosRepository")
public interface UsuariosRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuarios, Integer>{
```

Here a working example from our demo project:

https://github.com/zkoss/zkspringboot/blob/master/zkspringboot-demos/zkspringboot-demo-jar/src/main/java/org/zkoss/zkspringboot/demo/viewmodel/MainViewModel.java#L16-L20

---

Just for completeness (not trying to confuse):

There is also a way to let spring create your view model instances then the spring specific annotations are available `@Autowired`/`@Resource`. If that's desired please try to be specific with your questions.

Comment: Yeah, the VariableResolver did it. Though I do recall having the VariableResolver at one point, I probably and totally forgot about WireVariable. Kind of a good thing I steped back to check other stuff. Anyway, thank you and thanks to @M. Deinum for explaining me about the separate instances. It made so much sense after that. What confuses me right now is that one of my "blueprints" works with the Resolver. I'll dig further into that.

Comment: could be your example without the explicit @VariableResolver, has a [system level resolver](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/ZUML/EL_Expressions#System-level_Variable_Resolver) configured